# Automatically updating images assigned to properties in winform editor?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, compact-framework

I have a control in WinForms which has an exposed image property, I give the image property an image to use.

when I modifyu the source image the control still uses the old image and I have to re-assign the image to it so it displays the new updated image.

I was wondering if it was possible to automate this process, so when I change the source image the image used in the control is updated automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override the OnPaint method of the exposed Image property in order to repaint  when assign a new Image to use

Please see link for more information [Control.OnPaint Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx)

Comment: Nono, I mean when I modify the source image in paint or something like that then recompile the program and run it I find it's still using the old image... I don't think OnPaint will solve that issue...

Comment: Is the Image file embedded as content resource?